# Asp.net Page Optimization

Tags: asp.net

we are using ASP.net 4 webform & Sql server

need your inputs or guidance for the below url

[https://www.powerwale.com/store/exide-instabrite-ib1500-150ah-inverter-battery/77098]

for Page Optimization

1. Product details are being from Product table based on product id
2. Rating is fetching from another rating table, via sqldatareader (Some calculation)
3. images from other table based on the Product id ((Multiple records here)
4. similar Products is being fetched from similarproduct table ((Multiple records here)
5. explore related product section is being fetched from relatedproduct tables (Multiple records here)

we wanted to do somepage optimization..

Pls share you approach or guidance

1. will this lazy load on different sections for different table on same page will it help?
   any technicial guidance or some code to startup
2. we need to load the page faster? any other thoughts..

Thanks

Comment: From a rendered page, we cannot suggest changes to the code. Or is this meant as advertising?

Comment: No one can optimise code they cannot see, and without a clear description of the exact issue or any related metrics to back it up, and without understanding at least a little about the underlying business drivers for the overall design. You might as well show us a picture of your house and ask us if it was built to the correct standards, you would get the same answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are using the Entity framework the Lazy loading is the main drawback of it.see https://entityframework.net/ef-vs-nhibernate

I recommend you to usee Nhibernate because it supports a second-level cache, that can be used among multiple ISessionFactory. It might increase startup time due to metadata preparation, however, it goes so fast after that.